# Tomcat7 start/restart on Win7

Tags: tomcat7

I recently installed **Apache Tomcat 7** for Windows7 while trying to learn Servlets/JSP.

If I try to start Tomcat by double-clicking on the icon on my desktop (which maps to `C:\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat7\bin\tomcat7.exe`), it opens up a command prompt with many messages rolling and disappears

If this is start then how to restart ?

The first time I installed it, there was an icon in the system tray, clicking it one could start/stop the server. But that icon disappeared after the first time use. I uninstalled/re-installed apache. Again the icon appeared & disappeared the next time it was accessed.

Is there a way to bring back the icon for good, or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

tomcat7.exe is Tomcat itself, running in a Windows service wrapper.
tomcat7w.exe is the Monitor/Configure app.

You can use tomcat7w.exe for start/stop tomcat service.

Comment: what's wrong when it says: Unable to open the servise 'Tomcat7'

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin`

Start `Tomcat7w.exe` (GUI application).

Here you can start or stop the service from the General tab